# Complex integral with non integer power of the denominator

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I would like to solve this complex integral but I'm not able to use Residue Theorem because of the non integer power of the denominator. Do you have a trick for this problem ?

$$\int_{c_2 - i \infty}^{c_2 + i \infty} \frac{z e^z}{(\alpha-z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}\, dz$$

$\alpha$ and $c_2$ are positive and real numbers.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with branch cuts?

Comment: No I am not at all

Comment: That would be a good starting point.

Comment: It's a bit complex.

At first:
$ f(z) = \frac{z e^z}{(\alpha-z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$ is not continuous, 'cause ther are poles at $ z = 0 $, $ z = \sqrt{\alpha} $ and $ z = -\sqrt{\alpha} $.

That means that ou caan't use the contour integral for continuous functions:
$$\int f(z)~\operatorname{d}x=\int a(x)+b(x)\cdot\mathrm{i} ~\operatorname{d}x=\int a(x)~\operatorname{d}x+\int b(x)~\operatorname{d}x\cdot \mathrm{i}=A(x)+B(x)\cdot\mathrm{i}$$

Like $\oint_C f(z)\,dz = \oint_C \frac{1}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2}\,dz=2\pi i \,\operatorname{Res}_{z=i}f(z)=2\pi i\left(-\frac{i}{4}\right)=\frac{\pi}2$